# Running Anaconda's python version in powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I had python installed from the official Python.org installer but afterward I installed Anaconda. Now when running the script Powershell is not using Anaconda's version of Python but the previously installed version. I already changed the environment path but still the problem persists. How can I make Powershell to use Anaconda's version of Python?

Comment: Does your script have a shebang line?

Comment: What is exactly a shebang line?

Comment: Have you tried [googling](http://www.google.com)? In any case [read here for an explanation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script). It was the first hit on google.

Comment: No, my script does not have a shebang line like this #!

Comment: What does `get-command python.exe` return? And `($env:Path).Replace(';',"\`n")`?

Comment: with get-command python.exe I get Command type: Application     Name: python.exe. The list of Paths includes among others C:\Python27, C:\Miniconda3, C:\Miniconda3\Scripts C:\Anaconda C:\Anaconda\Scripts

Comment: As you can see `$env:PATH` still contains your `C:\python27` path. And probably before the Anaconda path. That is your problem. You probably need to restart the system.

Comment: Already restarted the system but still the problem remains. The environment path shown in Powershell are not as appear in system properties so I don't know how to change them.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the problem by changing the path directly on Powershell in which C:\Python27 is after C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts. Check current path using:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).Path
```

And create a new path using:

```
$newPath=’Write new path’
```

Change to new path:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH –Value $newPath
```